# call functions with arguments returned by a custom hook in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

basically, I'd like to pass an argument to a function of a custom hook that then is returned so I can call it in another place. I'd like to pass certain arguments to a function and not to a hook because I format the object argument to that function in another function, and hooks can't be called inside functions. this is the code of the hook:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

export const usePutData = () => {
  const [errorCode, setErrorCode] = React.useState("");
  const [severity, setSeverity] = React.useState("");
  const [loadingPut, setLoadingPut] = React.useState(true);

  function axiosPut(url, obj) {
    axios
      .put(url, obj, { timeout: 2000 })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response !== null) {
          setSeverity("success");
        } else {
          setSeverity("warning");
          setErrorCode(window.$errReq);
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setSeverity("warning");
        setErrorCode(
          error.response
            ? error.response.status + " - " + error.response.statusText
            : error.request
            ? window.$errReq
            : error.message
            ? error.message
            : "errorrr"
        );
      })
      .finally(() => setLoadingPut(false));
  }

  return [errorCode, severity, loadingPut, axiosPut];
};
```

Comment: what's stopping you from calling `axiosPut` with arguments?

Comment: @Ramesh Reddy it prints an error in the console saying axiosPut is not a function.

Comment: add the code that's using `axiosPut`

Comment: @Ramesh Reddy axiosPut("/api/configuration", obj);

Comment: Add more code to the question, how are you using the custom hook to get `axiosPut`?

Comment: @RameshReddy 
  const { errorCode, severity, loadingPut, axiosPut } = usePutData();

there are long compononents, thats why i tried to cut out unnecessary code, as i said, i call the hook, get the returns in the top of the component, and then in the onSubmit function i would like to call the hook with an object that is formated inside that function

Comment: The issue is with destructuring. Check my answer.

Comment: @RameshReddy yep, i don't know what i was thinking

Answer (score 0):

The custom hook is returning an array. So you have to use array destructuring instead of object destructuring.

```
const [ errorCode, severity, loadingPut, axiosPut ] = usePutData()
```

Alternately you can return an object from the custom hook.